# Laravel 5.2 Error creating a many to many relationship

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2 and I am getting the following error when trying to create a many to many relationship between a Country and a Currency:

```
ErrorException in helpers.php line 748: 

preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array
```

I have the following Country and Currency models defining the many to many relationships:

```
class Country extends Model
    {
    protected $table = 'country';

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function region()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Region');
    }

    public function destinations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Destination');
    }

    public function currencies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Currency', 'country_currency')->withTimestamps();
    }
}


class Currency extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'currency';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'code', 'sell_rate', 'buy_rate',     'min_denomenation', 'enabled'];

    public function countries()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Country', 'country_currency')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Here is a snippet of the form I use for adding countries (to a region) where you can select multiple currencies that get posted as an array to my controller method:

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3  form-group">
        <label for="currencies">Currency: </label>
        <select class="form-control" name="currencies[]" id="currencies" multiple>
            @foreach($currencies as $currency)
                <option value="{{$currency->id}}">{{$currency->name}}    </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
```

My CountryController is as follows with the createCountry method being called when the form is posted:

```
class CountryController extends Controller
{

    public function add(Region $region)
    {
        $currencies = Currency::all(['id', 'name']);
        return view('admin.destinationeditor.country.add', compact('region', 'currencies'));
}

    public function createCountry(CountryRequest $request, Region $region)
    {

        $country = $region->countries()->create($request->all());

        $currencyIds = $request->input('currencies');

        $country->currencies()->attach($currencyIds);

        flash()->success('Success!', 'The country page was successfully added to the region');

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

}

The issue is seems to be arising when I pass the `$currencyIds` to `attach()` method.

If I do not post any currencies, the country is created with no issues but when I try to post currency values, the issue occurs.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Cheers,
Jim

Comment: Can you try to use **sync** instead of **attach** and see if you get the same error.

Comment: @TheFallen I have just given that a try but the same errror is occurring

Comment: Can you var_dump `$currencyIds` and see if it's a one dimensional array?

Comment: This is what is being returned:

array:2 [▼
  0 => "2"
  1 => "3"
]

Comment: So it might not be caused by the relation. Best way to find out is to go to *vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php* at line 748 where you'll have **preg_replace()** and var_dump the parameters of the function. One of them should be causing this error because *preg_replace* expects it to be a string and it's array.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by creating both the relational function in **Currency** model and **Country** model? I mean You have created the function from **Country** model but haven't created any from **Currency** model.I don't know bro but you can check that. :) :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have created Currency models from another form and they are creating fine. It's just when I pull the currencies into the country form and try to relate them i'm running into the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get to the bottom of this issue. I changed the `$guarded` property to `$fillable` but had a typo in this!